# Problems with media queries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

So I'm building my personal site using bootstrap.  Currently I'm trying to make the content fit at the mobile sizes.

My problem is I can't quite remember how to use `queries` and the way I'm doing it stops working at a certain point.

So basically what I'm doing is putting the mobile CSS style in the main CSS then altering it as the screen gets bigger.

But for some reason the queries stop working after `992px`.

Is there a better way to do this that will work and make more sense.

Comment: if you don't remember then read again the tutorial you first read. Also post your code here - some of us are too lazy to visit links

Comment: I looked at a couple tuts and it just didn't click for me.  Sorry bout the code for some reason my spacing is messed up in my style sheet so I cant just go line my line and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you should use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

Remember use the sizes you like/need. This below is just for demo purposes.

**Non-Mobile First Method** using **`max-width`**:

```css
/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }       
    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/ 
    }
```

**Mobile First Method** using **`min-width`**:

```css
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }       
    @media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/ 
    }
```

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.w3.org/Talks/2013/0516-CSS-WWW2013/media-queries.html) from W3.org

Comment: Oh okay that's why it was weird I was using mobile first and i'm used to the non mobile first.  I'm most likely going to switch it around so that it makes more sense to me.  Hopefully that will correct the not working after a certain point problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I actually figured out my problem.  Im developing on retina screen.  so i added in pixel densities and that fixed the problem.