# the 1px gap when using min and max with media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have been dealing with an issue with `min` and `max width` usage in the last few years with websites I am developing for the company I work for.

Though I can easily get around this by just changing the breaking points, it annoys that I don't know why it is happening and I keep walking into this issue after the websites have had some modifications.

So the issue is probably most know for the non-100% gap.
This issue though is not related to screen zoom but rather just a breakpoint that isn't functioning like would be expected from it or at least how I expect it to work.

(For the example I put together a situation this happens in. There are some situations that something along these lines happens in the development process)

For this example I have 2 `div`'s with classes `test1` and `test2` respectively.

```
<div class="test1">
  test 1
</div>
<div class="test2">
  test 2
</div>
```

Both `div`'s should be hidden normally but in certain situations you would want them to show.
So lets say we get to the situation where we want to show `test2` on desktop and `test1` on mobile.
That would result in a CSS like below

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .test2{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .test1{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Now comes the weird part.
As soon as I show the website and start resizing the page both will be visible at exactly 768px width which is not the desired result.

The reason I don't understand why this happens is that when I look on the internet I only read that a media query basically does the following (as far as I understand it)

> **For min-width:**
> IF the viewport is equal to or bigger than the min-width, apply the styling in the media query
>
> **For max-width:**
> IF the viewport is lesser than or equal to the max-width, apply the styling in the media query

If you would practically apply this you would think that the moment the viewport reaches the 768px breakpoint both media queries would trigger and hide the test2 div and show test1.

Hope someone could shed some light on this for me.

I also made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/controvi/pen/zRvGRR) example

Kind regards.

Comment: I don't get it, you had the answer in front of you eyes and you even wrote it in your question ^^.
"For min-width:
IF the viewport is equal to or bigger than the min-width, apply the styling in the media query
For max-width:
IF the viewport is lesser than or equal to the max-width, apply the styling in the media query"
lesser or equal, and bigger or equal. So 768 is the equal moment for both ... ^^

Comment: @AlexVand though you are completely correct in this I do find that i get this issue in other ways.
Sad thing though is that I can't replicate them.
Take bootstrap for example. the menu , at least for me, by default has a breakpoint issue on 768. Because of that the tablets like ipads break the website. sorry that i can't give you a good example of what I try to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the same breakpoint for `min/max-width`.

That's why when `min-width` is used it's added a pixel or other way around subtracting a pixel to `max-width`.

With this in mind, you have 2 options:

First

```css
@media (min-width: 769px) {
.test2{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .test1{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Second

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.test2{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .test1{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

You can read about [media queries order matters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336611/css-media-queries-order-matters/29336716#29336716)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a very simple logic.Both of the div will be visible for 768, because you defined 768 in the media query for min and max.
This is the right way to do that:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.test2{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .test1{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: @dippas answerd it a little bit more detail and it makes me understand your answer a bit better. Thank you for replying to my question.

Comment: And now it doesn't work in firefox since it's pixels are not integer numbers

Answer (score 1):

It can also be applied using this method:

```css
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .test2{
    display: block;
  }
  
  .test1{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .test1{
    display: block;
  }
  
  .test2{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  test 1
</div>
<div class="test2">
  test 2
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me an example of how it could also be applied. Though it does not really answer the question I have I do appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
@media (min-width: 768.99px) {
 .test2
  {
  display: block;
  }
}
```

this will resolve the 1px issue

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However my tests in Chrome resulted in other breakpoint-related issues. So, I set the value to a half pixel and it appears to work in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting topic. I have still ran into strange issues using the answers in this post.

Using Bootstrap to create a mega menu and between breakpoints 991px (down) and 992px (up), I get a moment of bs default menu styling. It seems to mainly happen in Chrome, but when I inspect the menu in responsive mode, I can recreate the issue in both FireFox and Chrome.

The only way I resolved the issue in both browsers was to set the max-width (breakpoint and down) to 991.5px