# media query is 1px off

Tags: css, media-queries

I put this in my CSS:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .home #wrap {
    margin-top: 14px;
    }
}
```

so I expect it to trigger when the screen width is 767px or less. However it doesn't apply at 767px, only at 766px and less. Why is it 1px off?

**UPDATE:**

It's not a duplicate question. The asker in the other thread used 768px for both minimum and maximum, and for some reason didn't get why they overlapped. I'm using 767 for maximum and 768 for minimum, and don't understand why there is a 1px gap when there shouldn't be.

Take a look at the [site](https://yacs.dk/en/) if you like.

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve]. It might be an issue simiar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559799/10283047, or something else altogether. Rather impossible to tell with the information you have given so far.

Comment: then add 768.. if it works like that..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sir this is the perfect answer for this question ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the 1px gap when using min and max with media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559700/the-1px-gap-when-using-min-and-max-with-media-queries)

Comment: `max-width` is inclusive so this is weird. The problem is somewhere else. Post more code.

Comment: @misorude I really don't know how to go about that. Perhaps you could just take a look at the site? www.yacs.dk

Comment: @ReddaJoppe, did you fix this yet? EDIT: I had the exact same problem. Solution: Use <code>@media screen and (max-device-width: 767px)</code>. WHY: For me it had to with windows screen zooming. My screen resolution is set to 1920x1080, but I have it zoomed by 125%, when I used <code>max-width</code> it didn't work, but then I found out <code>max-device-width</code> and it worked.

Comment: @yuko Can confirm this solution. Do you know why windows is affecting media queries?

Comment: @dude, unfortunately, I don't understand why :(

Comment: For me, the issue wasn't with 125% scaling in windows (which I continue to use). Instead, the issue was displaying my screen on my external monitor connected with my laptop (through hdmi if it matters). In that scenario, I would get the media queries being off by 1px. However, if I displayed my screen on my laptop monitor, that no longer happened and everything worked normally with the css media queries working exactly as they're supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I decreased the pixel size one-by-one in the devtool width box and then console-logged window.innerWidth, it reveals what is likely a math rounding issue.

```
DevBoxWidth | window.innerWidth
770px | 770px
**769px | 770px**
768px | 768px
767px | 767px
766px | 766px
**765px | 766px**
764px | 764px
763px | 763px
762px | 762px
**761px | 762px**
760px | 760px
```